# EXTJS 4 Custom Plugins and/or Features where to place

Tags: extjs4.1

So I've set my project up using sencha cmd. I have the following dir

```
app
 -model
 -view
 -store
 -controller
```

If I create custom plugins or feature where should I place them under views, or some other location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following directory structure:

```
app
    controller
    model
    plugins
    store
    view
```

You then include each plugin in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/plugins/SomePlugin.js"></script>
```

There is some sense though to have the following folder structure as plugins are component plugins thus are part of the view layer:

```
app
    view
        plugins
```

Comment: That's what I was going to do, but just wanted to make sure that was correct. I also added a ux dir too.

Comment: Technically, you should be using the Ext.Loader (and "requires" config) to load the plugin - not adding the script tag to HTML.

Comment: @arthurakay - I agree. The script tag version is shorter and easier for this purpose though...